# IMPORT RANGE PARSE ERROR

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, importrange

I have this arrayformula where I need to match cells in a column from one worksheet to another and I used Importrange to link these two but it's giving me errors and I'm not sure what i'm missing

here is the formula

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A:A)=1,"Existing in Tracker Portal (Checker)",IF(ISBLANK(G:G),"",IF(ISERROR(MATCH(G:G,=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rGfFG0jeUdcP1ynladinQalNpcuVbuz92iqF6goUqzA/edit#gid=0","Existing!A:A"),0)),"NO","YES"))))`

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. `IF(ISERROR(MATCH(G:G,=IMPORTRANGE("`  remove the equals (=) sign.

Comment: If "from one worksheet to another" means "from one tab to another within the same spreadsheet file", you should not be using `importrange()` in the first place. Use a simple range reference like `Existing!A:A` instead.